# JQuery basic selector usage and non unique element ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'am maintaining a GUI built using JQuery. In one part of the GUI,
multiple tabs can be opened to edit data.

When a new tab is opened, it is created by cloning the first tab content div and
updating the input fields in the div.

The new tab is given a unique ID based on the tab index, but all
other ID's within the cloned tab div are the same as the original tab div.

Now, that seems to cause problems since ID's are not unique any
more. When selecting an input field the following works on Firefox 3.6.8:

```
$('#tabs-2 #scriptName').val( data.name );
```

This selects the tab div with ID tabs-2 and then selects the input
field within that div with the ID scriptName and sets its value. Now
this does not work on Chrome or Firefox 3.0.19.

The DOM hierachy looks something like this

```
<div id="tabs">
     <div id="tabs-1">
         ...
         <input id="scriptName"/>
         ...
     </div>
     ...
     <div id="tabs-2">
         ...
         <input id="scriptName"/>
         ...
     </div>
 </div>
```

One solution would be to make all ID's wihtin the cloned tab content
div unique, but that seems like a brute force aproach. It must be
possible to address the content within a div in a more independent way
without require a unique ID.

The cloning of the whole div when generating a new tab is of course a
crude hack, a more elegant solution would be to reuse the same div but
change the content depending on the selected tab, but that is how it
is built right now and unfortunately it was developed and tested using a later
firefox browser where this selector worked.

**Pre-post EDIT**

I found a lot of related questions with answers that gave some hints on how to solve this, when I inserted my offline-edited question, but I post this question anyway since good suggestions for how to solve this are always welcome.

**EDIT**

I'am trying the class approach right now, I do have one problem though, some input fields uses labels with for attribute, the for attribute must point to a unique id. But that can be solved by omitting the for attribute and make the input field a nested element instead.

Comment: In HTML, ID attributes **must** be unique within **the same HTML document**.

Comment: As @BoltClock says, IDs **must** be unique. I think jQuery's clone() function clones and drops the ID: http://api.jquery.com/clone/ Maybe that is a better approach?

Comment: Yep I know that, so the solution would be to address all tab content within the div identified by the unique ID by pure spatial relationship, e.g $('div#tabs-1').child().child() ... ?

Comment: @BoltClock is correct.  See [the HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). Having non-unique id attributes in a document will cause you no end of grief due to inconsistency in handling them across all browsers.

Comment: @Pekka, nope JQuery's clone does not drop the ID, it generates duplicated element ID's... I'm starting to get irritated on the contractor who built this and only tested it in one browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's are unique identifiers.  The moment you introduce a duplicate id, you have an invalid document on your hands.

The best way to get around this is to refrain from using id's on anything that is going to be cloned.  Instead, use a "unique" class name to identify the element.  Then, when it is cloned, you can walk down the DOM to each copy of the class.  jQuery has very good DOM traversal methods for this.

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

**Additionally:** `.children()`, `.parent()`, `.parents()`, and `.siblings()` are particularly useful.  I'd stay away from `.find()` unless it cannot be helped.  `.find()` can be slow if you are searching through many, many nodes in the DOM.  Since you're building an interface, this might be the case.

Comment: The ID's are unique was something that struck me initially, I believe that the CSS class should have been used instead.

It now works, but I'am struggling with the CSS stylesheet to make it all look right again ;)

Answer (score 2):

just a suggestion, can you make id of the input as class? So that you don't have a problem when cloning. and your code would be something like, `$('#tabs-2 .scriptName').val( data.name );`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know will it helps in your case but you can try .find() jQuery method.

Try something like this expression:

```
$('#tabs-2').find('#scriptName').val( data.name );
```

Comment: While the other commenters are correct (HTML ID attributes are supposed to be globally unique within the page), the approach you suggest does seem to work in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

I have a AngularJS app where I ran into the same problem when ng-repeating elements. Heres how I solved it.

Your tabs, the parent element, have unique ID's right? So just go down the children of that tab. Snipit from my div-windows to get children for resizable parent and alsoResize (or manualy resize as in my case) the children. Hint: I just left the IDs out of the children. $scope.panes[] is my window array, I just grab the ID and each out the children:

```
var objParent = $('#' + $scope.panes[index].windID); //entire div window
var objChild = [];
//objChild[0] = title bar
//objChild[1] = contentpane
objParent.children().each(function(i){
    objChild[i] = $(this);
});
```

Another solution would be to built the whole tab as a string and innerHTML it to the page. This way you can do someting like this with the ids: (again my div-window example)

```
child1ID = "id='"+windID+titlebar+"'";
child2ID = "id='"+windID+contentpane+"'";
```