# Ajax keeps sending undefined

Tags: jquery

I've made a form for a guestbook for school with ajax, only it keeps sending undefined instead of the values.

the jquery code:

```
$(".forum-index.admin-table tr .save").click(function(){
    var id = '';
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert($("."+id+" #volgorde").val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: site_url+"content/order_cat.php",
        data: 'submit=submit&title='+ $("."+id+" #title").val() +'&desc='+ $("."+id+" #desc").val() +'&volgorde='+ $("."+id+" #volgorde").val() +'&zichtbaar='+ $("."+id+" #zichtbaar").val() +'&id='+id,
        success: function(html) {
            $(".forum-index.admin-table")
                        .fadeOut("fast")
                        .empty()
                        .trigger("destroy")
                        .append(html)
                        .fadeIn("fast");
            click();
        }
    });
});
```

the Html:

```
<table width='100%' class='forum-index tables admin-table' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr class='top'><td><h3>General</h3></td><td>topics</td><td colspan='3'>order</td></tr>                             
<tr class='2'>
    <td><span><a href='#'>test cat onzichtbaar</a></span>
            <br><small>Deze categorie is nu alleen zichtbaar voor de admins</small>
    </td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='volgorde' id='volgorde' value='2' style='width:40px;' /></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' title='visibility' id='zichtbaar' value='aan' name='zichtbaar' checked /></td>
        <td id='2' class='imgFade save'>&nbsp;<img src="http://bas-peters.nl/Forum2/images/save.png"><img src="http://bas-peters.nl/Forum2/images/save_color.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you should send object as data, not string

Comment: there's nothing wrong with using a string instead. jquery will just convert the object to a string anyway.

Comment: Most likely your selectors (such as `$("."+id+" #title")`) are returning 0 elements.

Comment: I don't know. i've tried in the console of my browser and also there i get undefined back

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it as follows:

```
function traceMsg(msg) {
    // Comment the function to disable logging; 
    // This works in Google Chrome and Firefox.        
    console.log(msg);
}

$(".forum-index.admin-table tr .save").click(function(){

    // this statement is unnecessary
    // var id = ''; 
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    traceMsg("id = " + id); // this is generally useful to see what happens in your source code
    traceMsg("title = " + $("."+id+" #title").val()); // if your tag with 'title' ID is not unique, it is plain wrong (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405351/jquery-basic-selector-usage-and-non-unique-element-id). Much more reasonable seems to use the selector $("#"+id+" .title").

    // Use an object rather than query string to specify data you want to post.
    var dataObject = {
        submit: "submit",
        title: $("."+id+" #title").val(),
        desc: $("."+id+" #desc").val(),
        // and so on
    };

    traceMsg("dataObject = ");        
    traceMsg(dataObject);
    traceMsg("Submitting data to " + site_url+"content/order_cat.php");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: site_url+"content/order_cat.php",
        data: dataObject ,
        success: function(html) {
            traceMsg(html);
            $(".forum-index.admin-table")
                        .fadeOut("fast")
                        .empty()
                        .trigger("destroy")
                        .append(html)
                        .fadeIn("fast");
            click();
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** You enter query string:

```
data: 'submit=submit&title='+ $("."+id+" #title").val() + ....
```

Now consider what happens when `$("."+id+" #title").val()` returns a string like this `rock&roll`. The query string will be wrong because you do not escape ampersands! The object `dataObject` is converted to a query string in a safe manner (i.e. escaping is done properly).

Comment: Hello, Tanks for your answer, but now it stil doesn't send anything. only now it sends emtpy vars instead of vars with value undefined

      -edit- the tag title is indeed not unique.

Comment: i've changed all the ids to classes, but it only send the id and submit

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your code. Use traceMsg function calls to see what is going on in your code. If data are not send to order_cat.php then try to add `traceMsg(dataObject);` to see what is in the object.

Comment: The object returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

i've done a bit of research. I needed to use .prop("value") instead of .val(). now it works until ajax loads in the updated version.

Comment: Your segment of HTML code is too short and there is no "desc", "title" that you send via AJAX request. It's hard to help you in such circumstances. However, check jQuery documentation: *The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.* (http://api.jquery.com/val/)