# jQuery selectors - strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I found a strange behavior of jQuery selectors. When the page contains some elements with not unique ids, jQuery returns different results for the same selectors:

Html:

```
<button id='btn1'>Button 1</button>
<button id='btn1'>Button 2</button>
<button id='btn3'>Button 3</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#btn1')        - returns one element: button1
$('#btn1 ')       - returns two elements: button1, button2
$('#btn1, #btn3') - returns three elements: button1, button2, button3
```

I want to know - it is jQuery bug or it has logical explanation?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alexmac/5wf2W/1/)

Comment: ID must be unique

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery basic selector usage and non unique element ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405351/jquery-basic-selector-usage-and-non-unique-element-id)

Comment: Yes i know, i want to know why jQuery works so.

Comment: I think it is the difference between [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) & [Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: If you want to know why, you would have to look at the source code for jQuery's Css selector engine

Comment: @ArunPJohny was about to post the same thing :)

Comment: `#btn1` and `#btn1[space]` are not the same selector...

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol what about the third selector? Why it returns three elements?

Comment: 1 id might use getElementById which gives first hit, many use QSA+ "[id='btn1'],[id='btn2']", which returns all matches. as using alert(btn1) in js returns an element for single hits or collection if there are more than one.

Comment: @JamesFair As i know StackOverflow ceil to ask questions and get  answers. Any answer can be found in source code, but why we need SO in this case?

Comment: Interesting, according to the [Sizzle src](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L99) it does appear to try and apply a right trim on the selector.  And a quick test (http://jsfiddle.net/9zs3R/) appears to show it working just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that this appears to be strange behavior but it likly isn't being addressed directly by the jQuery developers precisely because of the HTML standard which requires ID attributes to uniquely identify elements. You shouldn't consider this behavior to be consistent.

Now as for the related issue of fixing it, it is fascinating (to me at least) how one would prioritize fixing an invalid edge case. Maybe there are performance implications in sanitizing all selectors to prevent unpredictable results when misused.

The selector engine that powered jQuery is called [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com) incase you wanted to dig deeper into how and why it produces the output that it produces and there is also a suite of unit tests (written with the QUnit framework).

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how the browser's selectors work:

http://i.imgur.com/mGNJHe9.png

This is working as intended; your code should be corrected to not have duplicate IDs.